# What is the difference between closureOf and delegateClosureOf in Gradle Kotlin DSL

Tags: gradle, kotlin, closures, gradle-kotlin-dsl

[The official doc](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/kotlin_dsl.html) says:

> You may sometimes have to call Groovy methods that take Closure arguments from Kotlin code. For example, some third-party plugins written in Groovy expect closure arguments.
>
> In order to provide a way to construct closures while preserving Kotlin’s strong typing, two helper methods exist:
>
> - `closureOf<T> {}`
> - `delegateClosureOf<T> {}`
>
> Both methods are useful in different circumstances and depend upon the method you are passing the `Closure` instance into.
>   Some plugins expect simple closures.
>   In other cases, the plugin expects a delegate closure.
>   There sometimes isn’t a good way to tell, from looking at the source code, which version to use. Usually, if you get a `NullPointerException` with `closureOf<T> {}`, using `delegateClosureOf<T> {}` will resolve the problem.

Well, I have nothing againgst try-fail-fix approach, but maybe there is a deterministic way to tell in advance which method to use and why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> but maybe there is a deterministic way to tell in advance which method to use

Sure by simply examining the source code of the plugin you are configuring. For example, their Bintray plugin example is:

```
bintray {
    pkg(closureOf<PackageConfig> {
        // Config for the package here
    })
}
```

If you were to examine the source, you'll find this: https://github.com/bintray/gradle-bintray-plugin/blob/master/src/main/groovy/com/jfrog/bintray/gradle/BintrayExtension.groovy#L35..L37

```
def pkg(Closure closure) {
    ConfigureUtil.configure(closure, pkg)
}
```

That is a *simple* `Closure` so `closureOf<T> {}` would be appropriate here according to the docs.

Now their other example is for the Gretty Plugin when configuring farms:

```
farms {
    farm("OldCoreWar", delegateClosureOf<FarmExtension> {
        // Config for the war here
    })
}
```

If you examine the source, you'll find this: https://github.com/akhikhl/gretty/blob/master/libs/gretty-core/src/main/groovy/org/akhikhl/gretty/FarmsConfig.groovy#L23..L32

```
  void farm(String name = null, Closure closure) {
    if(name == null)
      name = ''
    def f = farmsMap_[name]
    if(f == null)
      f = farmsMap_[name] = createFarm()
    closure.delegate = f
    closure.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST
    closure()
  }
```

That's much more complex than the previous example and according to the docs, since this clearly expects delegate closure, then `delegateClosureOf<T> {}`  would be the appropriate choice.